# how do i find a div element by searching in selenium, and then copying an attribute from that div using selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

what i am trying to do is getting the asin (an attribute) from a div (element) in html to then concatenate with amazon.com/dp/ + asin to form a url which is to then be visited. the divs have no id but are identified by the data-index="1" attribute within the div element so i am wondering how to call this div element to then be specifically searched for the asin attribute. thanks for reading.
using python 3.7 and selenium webdriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

email = ('.')
password = ('.')
query = ('macbook')

urls = []
prices = []
names = []
descs = []

def  search_amazon(query):
    driver.get('https://amazon.com/')
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
    time.sleep(2)
    searchBox.send_keys(query)
    searchBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)

    firstResult = driver.find_element_by_name('data-index="1"')
    asin = firstResult.getAttribute('data-asin')
    print(asin)
    url = 'https://amazon.com/dp/' + asin
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)

    return url

search_amazon(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these two lines of code with the code I have provided.

```
firstResult = driver.find_element_by_name('data-index="1"')
asin = firstResult.getAttribute('data-asin')
```

Since `data-index` is not the name its an attribute.You can use following **css** selector.

```
firstResult = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-index="1"]>div')
asin = firstResult.get_attribute('data-asin')
```

Here is the working code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

email = ('.')
password = ('.')
query = ('macbook')

urls = []
prices = []
names = []
descs = []

def  search_amazon(query):
    driver.get('https://amazon.com/')
    searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
    time.sleep(2)
    searchBox.send_keys(query)
    searchBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)

    firstResult = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-index="1"]>div')
    asin = firstResult.get_attribute('data-asin')
    print(asin)
    url = 'https://amazon.com/dp/' + asin
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)

    return url

search_amazon(query)
```